# What's the default caching behaviour for EclipseLink? and how to enable a L2 cache in-proc?

Tags: java, eclipselink

What's the default caching behaviour for EclipseLink?

I have a multi-threaded Java SE server and create a EntityManager per thread using the ThreadLocal pattern. I would like to able some sort of L2 cache to cache data in the server process. How can i do this?

Thanks

Comment: have you searched for "eclipselink second level cache"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EclipseLink enables its shared L2 cache by default.  You do not need to do anything to enable it.

To disable it see,
http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/FAQ/How_to_disable_the_shared_cache%3F

I would not recommend creating an EntityManager per thread.  You should normally create an EntityManager per request, or per transaction, or per session at most.  You should have a singleton EntityManagerFactory.